# Error Creating Project - 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, flutter, virtualization

I just installed Android Studio on my Windows 10 System. I got some error related to Virtualization (for Android emulation as my virtualization was disabled), I enabled virtualization and restarted my PC. Then I installed Flutter and Dart's plugin. Now I am getting this error whenever I am trying to create a Flutter project in Android Studio - 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What I have tried -

> Reinstalled Android Studio,
>   Deleted folder related to Android Studio from user folder (ie. C:\Users\username)

What else should I try?

'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you put flutter in your path environment variables? Make sure you follow the flutter steps step by step https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Oh no I missed some steps. Thank you so much Joe, I feel really silly to post this issue here..

Comment: It's all good it happens! No worries mate cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=>Go To Control Panel>>All Control Panel Items>>System

=>Click on **Advanced** Option then Click On **Environment** Variables

=> In User Variables Add

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

=> In System Variables add

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\

%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

%SystemRoot%\system32   

%SystemRoot%
```

Then Restart Your System And Run Android Studio create a flutter Project after specifying the sdk path !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put flutter in your path (the environment variables).Also make  sure you follow the flutter steps step by step:

[Flutter Windows Steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)